# From what initial time does `NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived` starts counting

Tags: c#, .net, networking

According to documentation, `NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived` returns the number of bytes that were received on the interface.

The question is bytes received since **when**?

I've found nothing so far on the internet and on the official MSDN page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BytesReceived` getter returns the `inOctets` value of the `MibIfRow2` struct which maps to the [`MIB_IF_ROW2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814491(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI structure.

The values there are also used for SNMP queries and from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760781 we learn that those values are simply updated by adding the new reading to the previous inOctets value. The inOctets value will overflow its maxvalue without error and continue from 0.

With this knowledge there is no **when**.

If you need the bytes received over a certain period it is up to you to query the value at the start of your desired time period and then later on query the value again. Substract the last value (check if the value hasn't overflowed/reset in the mean time) and the first value to get the number of bytes sent for your time frame.